# VBA Selecting Multiple File Paths and Saving in Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I can save one file path to my desired cell, I would like to be able to save more than one at a time. I have tried to change the code, yet I can't figure out how to save on the next row it just saves it all on the same line.

```
Dim FileFldr As FileDialog
Dim FileName, OrigFilePath, FileType, FilePath, CustID As String
Dim LastAttRow As Long
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
CustID = txtID.Value
Set FileFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FileFldr
   .AllowMultiSelect = True
   .Title = "Select file to attach"
   .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 1
   If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

   For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
   Next

    FilePath = .SelectedItems()
    FileName = Dir(FilePath)
    FileType = Right(FileName, Len(FileName) - InStr(Dir(FileName), "."))

   With Sheet6
        LastAttRow = .Range("D9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 
        .Range("D" & LastAttRow).Value = CustID 
        .Range("E" & LastAttRow).Value = FileName
        .Range("F" & LastAttRow).Value = FileType
        .Range("G" & LastAttRow).Value = FilePat
        .Range("H" & LastAttRow).Value = "=Row()"

   End With 
   NoSelection:
   End With 
   Sheet6.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Note - you don't do anything in your loop: `For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems`, then immediately `Next`.

Comment: Just move your NEXT after the END WITH.  Also you need to change FilePath = .SelectedItems() to FilePath = vrtSelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar way to do it, this will put each of the files attribtes on its own row in columns D to H.

Please note if you was to run this twice, whats selected the second time will overwrite whats already present and wont append to the end.
To change this behaviour you would need another variable to hold and preserve your filecount, then next time around when writing the array to the sheet start your range at your previous file count +1, then the end range to previous file count + your new file count.

```
    Sub newtest()

    Dim FileFldr As FileDialog
    Dim FileName, OrigFilePath, FileType, FilePath, CustID As String

    CustID = txtID.Value

    Set FileFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FileFldr
       .AllowMultiSelect = True
       .Title = "Select file to attach"
       .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 1
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

        Dim ArrayCount As Long: RowCount = 0 'counter to hold what number in the array your on : 'set this number to 0 where array starts
        Dim FileArray As Variant 'declare the array which will hold all the files user selected
        Dim FileCount As Long: FileCount = .SelectedItems.Count 'declare the long which will hold the amount of files the user has selected - set to the amount of selected files
            ReDim FileArray(FileCount, 4) 'redim the array to the size of the amount of files

       'loop through each of the selected items and assign its values to an address in the array
       For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            FilePath = vrtSelectedItem
            FileName = Dir(FilePath)
            FileType = Right(FileName, Len(FileName) - InStr(Dir(FileName), "."))

            FileArray(ArrayCount, 0) = CustID
            FileArray(ArrayCount, 1) = FileName
            FileArray(ArrayCount, 2) = FileType
            FileArray(ArrayCount, 3) = FilePath
            FileArray(ArrayCount, 4) = "=Row()"
            ArrayCount = ArrayCount + 1
       Next

        With Sheet6
            .Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(FileCount, 8)).Value = FileArray 'set range to what the array is and then put values from array in that range
        End With

    NoSelection:
       End With
       Sheet6.Activate

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code back with just a couple of changes. I think it does what you're looking for:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim FileFldr As FileDialog
  Dim FileName As String, OrigFilePath As String
  Dim FileType As String, FilePath As String, CustID As String
  Dim LastAttRow As Long
  Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
  CustID = txtID.Value
  Set FileFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FileFldr
 .AllowMultiSelect = True
 .Title = "Select file to attach"
 .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 1
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection

For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

 FilePath = Left(vrtSelectedItem, InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
 FileName = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
 FileType = Right(FileName, Len(FileName) - InStr(Dir(FileName), "."))

With Sheet6
 LastAttRow = .Range("D9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 .Range("D" & LastAttRow).Value = CustID
 .Range("E" & LastAttRow).Value = FileName
 .Range("F" & LastAttRow).Value = FileType
 .Range("G" & LastAttRow).Value = FilePath
 .Range("H" & LastAttRow).Value = "=Row()"
End With
Next
NoSelection:
End With
Sheet6.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I was looking for.